# Python bytes hiding inside string object

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of strings stored in a csv file, and some of them look like the following:

```
"b'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'"
```

Python treats this as a string, so I can not use decode to get the internal string in the correct format. How can I do this? As the end result, I would like to have:

```
"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

I have tried decode, loading the file in `'r'`, `'rb'`, and `'rt'` modes, using `str()` on the strings

This is the code I used to create and populate the csv file:

```
with open("scraped.csv", "a", newline='') as fd:
    print("writing data to csv file...")
    writer = csv.writer(fd)
    for comment in comments:
        writer.writerow([comment.encode("utf-8")])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote the CSV file incorrectly in the first place. If you want to ensure the data is specifically UTF-8, pass `encoding='utf-8'` to the `open` call, and *don't* call `.encode("utf-8")` on the string to write, just pass the string directly.

For fixing what you've already got, since you wrote the string form of `bytes` literals, [let Python parse the literals with `ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), then `decode` the resulting `bytes`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> bytesform = ast.literal_eval("b'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'")
>>> strform = bytesform.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(strform)
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score -1):

You could check if the string starts with b' and if it does make a substring starting from the first character after the ' until the last character before the '.

```py
if str.startswith("b'"):
    str = str[2:-1]
```

E.g.

```py
a = "b'test'"
print (a[2:-1]) #prints test
```

Comment: That breaks for strings with embedded `'`s (the delimiter will be `b""` instead), and won't handle escaped bytes like `\n` or the like.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't entirely understand what you mean

Comment: The OP's code would convert an actual newline at the end of the example string like so, `str('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n'.encode('utf-8'))` producing `"b'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\n'"`. Your solution would leave the literal backslash and the `n` in there, rather than recovering the original newline.

Comment: Oh ok, yes indeed it would. Thanks for the explanation!